# Button that opens a form, or closes if open

Tags: vb.net, if-statement

I'm new to VB.net and have a question I hope you can help me with.

I have a form which has a button on and when i press the button form 2 opens. I would then like for the button on form 1 to then close form 2 if it is pressed while form 2 is open.

I have the following code inside the button click sub..

```
Dim openForm As Form2
openForm =New Form2()


If Application.OpenForms. OfType(Of Form2).Any() Then

Form2.Close()

Else

openForm.Show()
openForm = Nothing

End If
```

Form 2 opens when I press the button the first time. However pressing the button again does nothing, the form doesn't close.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You always close the form object that you just created, not the one that the user is looking at.  You'll get lots of benefits from reading an introductory book about vb.net programming.  Knowing what As New does and understanding object references is important to get ahead.

Comment: That's because you've initialized a new instance of form2...

Comment: Ok thank you both. I have one on the way :)

Answer (score 1):

You are always creating a new instance of `Form2`, but you should really close the existing instance, and create new instance only if you want to open new form.

```
' We are keeping our opened form reference here!
Dim openForm As Form2

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        If Application.OpenForms.OfType(Of Form2).Any() Then
              ' No `openForm = new Form2` here - we need to close the existing instance
              ' and not to create new one
              openForm.Close()
        Else
            ' Create new instance only here!
            openForm = New Form2()
            openForm.Show()
        End If
```

Or

```
    Dim openForms = Application.OpenForms.OfType(Of Form2)()
    ' If there is Form2 instance opened
    If openForms.Any() Then
        ' Get it and close it!
        openForms.First().Close()
    Else
        Dim openForm As New Form2
        openForm.Show()
    End If
```

Comment: Ohh i see what i was doing wrong now. That's works great thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    If Application.OpenForms.OfType(Of Form2).Any() Then
        Application.OpenForms.OfType(Of Form2).ElementAt(0).Close()
    Else
        Form2.Show()
    End If
```